# How to configure TeamViewerQS skipping the EULA-Prompt?

Tags: powershell, package, teamviewer

I was looking for an option to package TeamViewerQS for Windows in a way that does not prompt the user for accepting the EULA or showing any other distracting prompts. Solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the Powershell-sample to disable any prompts during start/end of TeamViewerQS. Each REG-entry is for a different version of the tool:

```
# prepare registry for startup:
$reg = "HKCU:\\Software\TeamViewer"
if (!(Test-Path $reg)) {New-Item -Path $reg -Force -ea 0}
$null = New-ItemProperty -Path $reg -Name 'TeamViewerTermsOfUseAcceptedQS' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Value 1 -Force -ea 0
$null = New-ItemProperty -Path $reg -Name 'EulaByUserAccepted_QS' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Value 1 -Force -ea 0
$null = New-ItemProperty -Path $reg -Name 'IntroShown' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Value 1 -Force -ea 0

# disable exit-popup for v11:
$hta  = "$env:temp\TeamViewer\TeamViewer11_Exit.hta"
$null = New-Item -Path $hta -Force -ea 0
$null = Set-ItemProperty -Path $hta -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true
```

Happy packaging! It's a fantastic tool!